# Hanging lights from a gap?

Tags: lighting, concrete, patio, gap

I live in an apartment complex with a small-ish patio. Every year they have a decorating contest, and I always try to hang some lights using command hooks, but they never quite hold on to the concrete, so after a few days, I'm left with a mess.

Near the edge of the concrete, there's a small gap - about an inch wide and about 3/8" deep. I was wondering if there's some kind of expanding clamp (I have no idea what I'm searching for, so this is how I've been conceptualizing it) that I could put in the gap, tighten, and use that to hang lights from? I don't know if such a product exists, or what it would be called, so google is failing me.

I've attached a picture of the gap.

[image: Patio Roof]

Comment: try using a supermagnet to locate rebar inside the concrete ... the rebar may be close enough to the surface to hold the magnet securely .... actually, the edge of the balcony could be metal

Answer (score 1):

I think a bolt with an expansion nut (or coupling nut) would kind of give you the "expansion clamp" behavior you're looking for

Alternatively you could try "hardwall hangers", they nail into concrete fairly easy.When you're done you can pop them off with a screwdriver and the holes are small enough that I don't think it would cause any issues with your apartment complex